# Handling Multiple @client.on(events.NewMessage) Decorators in Telethon Leads to Unwanted Behavior

Tags: python, telethon

I'm working on a project using Telethon where I have two separate `@client.on(events.NewMessage)` decorators defined in different Python files (main.py and login.py). The first one is used for a dispatcher function that handles various commands and checks, and the second one initiates a login process by asking the user to input their email.

main.py:

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def dispatcher(event):
    # Code to handle various commands and checks
```

login.py ( using this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/62246569/10472495 )

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def start_login(event):
    # Code to start login process by asking for email
```

The issue I'm facing is that sometimes, regardless of the message content or the context, the bot responds with the login prompt `("Please enter your email")` from the start_login function in login.py, even when the start_login function is not explicitly called. This behavior is unintended and seems to occur due to a conflict between the two @client.on(events.NewMessage) decorators.

I'm looking for a way to manage or prioritize these event handlers so that the start_login function only triggers under the correct conditions without interfering with the dispatcher's functionality. How can I resolve this conflict and ensure that each function only responds when it's supposed to?

Any advice or suggestions on how to structure these event handlers to avoid such conflicts would be greatly appreciated.